# How to use Entity Framework context with dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I'm trying to setup a base Repository class that can use the Entity Framework edmx model context.  The problem I'm having is that I need to find an interface that the EF EDMX object context implements so I can pass to the constructor via dependency injections.  I've got around this before by using a DataFactory that creates it and stores it in the HttpContext but that kills the ability to unit test.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : EntityObject
{
        private MyDataModelContext _dataContext;
        private ObjectSet<T> dbset;

        protected BaseRepository(IObjectContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;
            dbset = _dataContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }

    .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always created a DataContextFactory that passes my own interface to the Context, and passed that to my repositories like so:

The context interface:

```
public IMyDataContext {
    // One per table in the database
    IDbSet<Class1> Class1s { get;set; }
    // etc

    // The standard methods from EF you'll use
    void Add( object Entity );
    void Attach( object Entity );
    void Delete( object Entity );
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

The context factory:

```
public class MyDataContextFactory : IMyDataContextFactory {
    public IMyDataContext GetContext() {
        // TODO: Use the service locator pattern to avoid the direct instanciation
        return new MyDataContext();
    }
}
```

The context factory interface:

```
public interface IMyDataContextFactory {
    IMyDataContext GetContext();
}
```

The repository:

```
public class MyClass1Repository {
    private readonly IMyDataContextFactory factory;
    public MyClass1Repository( IMyDataContextFactory Factory ) {
        // TODO: check for null
        this.factory = Factory;
    }
    public List<MyClass1> GetAll() {
        using ( IMyDataContext db = this.factory.GetContext() ) {
            return db.Class1s.ToList();
        }
    }
    // TODO: Other methods that get stuff
}
```

Then when I want to test the repository, I pass in a fake `IMyDataContextFactory` that returns a fake `IMyDataContext` from `GetContext()`.

In time I notice duplication in repositories, and can push certain methods into the base repository: `GetAll()`, `Save()`, `GetById()` sometimes if I have consistent primary keys, etc.

Comment: Does that only work for EF POCO objects?  I'm using EF EDMX model.

Comment: The only difference between using DbContext (mine) and ObjectContext (yours) is that IMyDataContext will have ObjectContext-specific methods like .AddObject() and .DeleteObject() instead of .Add() and .Remove().

Comment: The general premise is that the Context is query-agnostic, datastore-specific, the Repository is a strongly-typed wrapper that shims this to callers / the rest of the app as query-specific, data-store agnostic calls.  They pass in params, get back an object or list.  Swap to a new datastore, you gut the Context, rename innards of the Repositories, the rest of the app stays the same.

Comment: ... and the only thing that instantiates the DataContext is the factory, and nothing outside the Repositories ever references it.

Comment: So would this create a new instance of the Context per repository?  I'm using MVC and I thought it was good practice to only have one DataContext per request

Comment: It creates a new Context per repository method execution -- great because it contains the innards of EF, most specifically the SqlConnection.  Depending on how you set up your IoC, you can get the same factory instance passed into all repositories, and get the repositories also to behave like singletons.  In Ninject, this is .InSingletonScope()

Comment: Thanks for the help, the final piece to puzzle was letting my IoC device handle the scope of the DataContext.