# Good OOP Design Priciples for Handling Database Data

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop, database-design

I feel like I am asking a pretty basic question, and I think I should be able to find a good answer somewhere on the internet. But I am exhausted from searching and have only turned up a couple of dry bones. To top it all off, I am now frightened that this question is probably too subjective:)

Anyhow, here goes the question. What is considered good practice for accessing, processing, and manipulating data from a relational database in an object oriented program? So far in my programming I have been processing database data in a procedural sort of way. I am currently actively trying to improve my OOP habits and I wasn't sure how to handle this issue.

Here is one of the scenarios I am working with. I have a table with many manufacturing job entries in it. The application I am writing (improving) performs a lot of processing on each job. For example I iterate through each row in the table and do the following:

- Post the due date to Google calendar
- create a folder unique to the job in a given directory
- create a work order for the job
- create a contract brief for the job
- manages traveler documents
- email info to a couple people
- etc, the list goes on

You get the point. A lot of processing gets done on each job. Currently I have what most good programmers would call a fantastic crap pile of spaghetti code. Maybe it isn't quite that bad, but almost. I iterate through each row in the table with a for each loop and sequentially perform each action on each row. I don't like the way things are currently designed, but I don't know what to do better.

I would like if I could have a neat object called "Jobs" which would implement all the properties of a job and provide a method for performing each of the actions. Then I could even make a custom collection to handle my jobs and all the world would be brighter. The whole solution would be more readable, easier to maintain, easier to add actions to perform on each job (which happens frequently), etc.

But my problem is I can't figure out how to make the connection between the fancy objects and the database. Should I use some sort of Object-relational mapping (I read all kinds of mixed opinions about this)? Do I just loop through all the rows and convert them to objects which accumulate in a collection? Or is the best option to keep going about such projects in a procedural sort of way? I would love your answers and input.

I am interested in information on this subject in an abstract way. In other words I wonder how to handle a situation like this in general. Not just specific to the example I gave. But of course specifics are great as well. I do most of my programming in Visual Basic and C# with VS 2010.

Comment: Unfortunately,, abstract, generalized questions are not well suited to the stack overflow format. Please check out the site FAQ real quick for info on the sorts of questions you can ask here.

Comment: You should try NHibernate or Entity Framework and make your own opinion. In any case, for accessing your data from your data access layer - whatever it is - I strongly suggest you to use a Repository pattern between your DAL and your business layer.

Comment: Though sometimes you get lucky and some patient folks are on :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yeah, I know. I never know what to do when I think a question might be too general. I understand the issue, but the folks on StackExchange are just so good, that it makes it all the more tempting to ask:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Repository pattern.  It's a great way to separate data access from business processing in meaningful ways.  Applying this pattern I have a few projects:

- Entities - the objects that store stuff
- DataAccess - the ORM DbContext and ADO.NET wrappers
- Repository - wraps queries to present strongly-typed functions to the rest of the app
- TheRest - the other projects / tiers: Business, GUI, etc

See [How to use Entity Framework context with dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464388/how-to-use-entity-framework-context-with-dependency-injection/10464479#10464479) for a good description of each of the project types

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Repository pattern. From the reading I have done so far, it looks like that is the handle I needed.

Comment: +1 for dependency injection!  @ThinkerIV DI will help a great deal in fixing spaghetti code.  Some suggestions I would add: look into the difference between tiers and layers so as to not confuse the two.  I would suggest always having at least three layers, even if you have only one tier.  When you write a business layer, I would try to keep it stateless as much as possible.  Use data access objects to send and receive data to the business layer rather than having business objects that contain both data and functionality.

Comment: I thought the repository pattern was the way I should go until I ran across this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqaOxRbQmAQ&feature=related (not till part way through the video). Now I am thinking that maybe I should just use ORM without a repository

Comment: What's the timecode of the comment in this video?  There are arguments that your ORM is a sufficient "Repository" layer, but recall how often Microsoft changes their ORM / Data Access strategies.  (Remember typed data sets?)  If your repository abstracts away your ORM, and your entity objects are just C# objects, it's much easier when MS changes their mind.

Comment: @robrich The discussion I was referring to starts at [20:17](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqaOxRbQmAQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=1217s), I follow and somewhat agree with your logic, however the argument presented in the video is that you will need to make changes anyway. If you use a repository to abstract away your ORM, then you will still need to make changes in the repository when MS changes their mind, so why not just do it directly without a repository?

Comment: When MS changes their mind, you gut the ORM code in the DataAccess project, you modify the methods inside each repository, but the rest of the app doesn't change.  If you don't have this repository layer, then anything that instantiated a DbContext now also needs to change.  I can appreciate the "don't create an ivory tower for something simple" -- a very valid argument.  It totally depends on the scale of your app and what you're willing to maintain.  I don't like a "service" layer as it roughly duplicates the controller.  It's really only appropriate when you have multiple GUI clients.

Answer (score 1):

> But my problem is I can't figure out how to make the connection between the fancy objects and the database. Should I use some sort of Object-relational mapping (I read all kinds of mixed opinions about this)?

Yes.

As for the processing. Use the visitor pattern and let all different code which want to process the data register themselves as visitor. You could also use an inversion of control container to manage that (`IHandlerOf<Job>` or `IHandlerOf<TravelerDocument>`).

It gives you are more loosely coupled way of processing the data.